# How to create a sub directory inside a react project

Tags: reactjs, apache, .htaccess, react-router

I have a react project with routes defined and it looks like below.

```
http://myapp.com/home
http://myapp.com/projects
```

Now, I need to create a sub directory inside the application and create another react instance inside it, so that the url might look like.

```
http://myapp.com/subdirectory
```

But the parent react router is looking for a path match for `/subdirectory` and returns 404 since it cannot find it. How can I exclude react routing for this and ask the server to serve the files from that folder.

Comment: You'll have to configure this on the server to return one app's root index.html file or the other app's root index.html file, based on the request URL.

Comment: @DrewReese Can I use .htaccess to achieve this?

Comment: You may be able to, though I'm not very familiar so I'd not be of much further help. Hopefully someone more versed comes along.